# Android: How to scroll SpinnerView to item at position by default?

Tags: android, scroll, android-spinner

I have a Spinner View shows numbers between range 1500-1400, i want to auto scroll the spinner when user open it to specified position, ex: focus on 1436. how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use spinner.setselection(position) method.
Where position is the position value of the spinner item,which you want to get selected by default.